# What could be the reason that `apt update` says certificate is NOT trusted whereas curl says `SSL certificate verify ok`

Tags: linux, debian, ssl-certificate, installation, apt

I am trying to add docker to my Debian 11 bullseye installation.
until now, I have ran -

```
apt clean
apt update
update-ca-certificates
apt-get install -y ca-certificates
apt reinstall ca-certificates
```

but when I run `apt update` I keep getting

```
Err:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/debian bullseye InRelease              
  Certificate verification failed: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown.  Could not handshake: Error in the certificate verification. [IP: 2600:9000:2113:5000:3:db06:4200:93a1 443]
```

however, when I check the said repo using curl like so:
`curl -vI  'https://download.docker.com'`
the output indicates

```
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.docker.com
*  start date: Feb 22 00:00:00 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Nov 30 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "download.docker.com" matched cert's "*.docker.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; CN=Amazon RSA 2048 M02
*  SSL certificate verify ok
```

on what grounds does `apt` command reckon that the website certificate is not trusted, whereas `curl` thinks it can be trusted?

Comment: Btw, much simpler: `apt install docker.io`

Comment: The `docker.io` package available in Debian 11 is substantially older than the `docker-ce` package you get when using the official Docker apt repository.

Comment: Is apt configured to use a proxy?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I am not sure how to check this, anyway there is no ` /etc/apt/apt.conf` file if that answers

Comment: you have to read the instructions on how to use apt, apt by default don't allow any non trusted repository and therefore you need to add the trust by reading the manual provided by docker